# Using Schema Registry from Confluent with Avro and Kafka in Spring Boot Applications

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

First of all, I must say I'm not familiar with confluent.

I was following this tutorial: https://www.confluent.io/blog/schema-registry-avro-in-spring-boot-application-tutorial/ and I got stuck.

I couldn't create the consumer for Kafka because I've received an error: io.confluent.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "schema.registry.url" which has no default value.

I couldn't find this schema property in yml config.

The confluent is running locally:

```
$: confluent local start
zookeeper is already running. Try restarting if needed
kafka is already running. Try restarting if needed
schema-registry is already running. Try restarting if needed
Starting kafka-rest
kafka-rest is [UP]
Starting connect
connect is [UP]
Starting ksql-server
ksql-server is [UP]
Starting control-center
control-center is [UP]
```

After I setup users topic in Spring, from control-center I see a different schema:

```
{
  "connect.name": "ksql.users",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "registertime",
      "type": "long"
    },
    {
      "name": "userid",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "regionid",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "gender",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ],
  "name": "users",
  "namespace": "ksql",
  "type": "record"
}
```

These are my files:

user.avro

```
{"namespace": "com.example.demo.model",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "User",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "age",  "type": "int"}
 ]
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>






<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.10.0</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <!-- other dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>

            <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams-avro-serde</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <!-- other maven repositories the project -->
        <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

DemoApplication.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.NewTopic;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    @Value("${topic.name}")
    private String topicName;

    @Value("${topic.partitions-num}")
    private Integer partitions;

    @Value("${topic.replication-factor}")
    private short replicationFactor;


    @Bean
    NewTopic moviesTopic() {
        return new NewTopic(topicName, partitions, replicationFactor);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Consumer.java

```
package com.example.demo.kafka;

import com.example.demo.model.User;
import lombok.extern.apachecommons.CommonsLog;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@CommonsLog(topic = "Consumer Logger")
public class Consumer {


    @Value("${topic.name}")
    private String topicName;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "users", groupId = "group_id")
    public void consume(ConsumerRecord<String, User> record) {
        log.info(String.format("Consumed message -> %s", record.value()));
    }
}
```

KafkaController

```
package com.example.demo.kafka;

import com.example.demo.model.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")
public class KafkaController {

    private final Producer producer;

    @Autowired
    KafkaController(Producer producer) {
        this.producer = producer;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/publish")
    public void sendMessageToKafkaTopic(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("age") Integer age) {
        this.producer.sendMessage(new User(name, age));
    }
}
```

Producer.java

```
package com.example.demo.kafka;

import com.example.demo.model.User;
import lombok.extern.apachecommons.CommonsLog;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@CommonsLog(topic = "Producer Logger")
public class Producer {

    @Value("${topic.name}")
    private String TOPIC;

    private final KafkaTemplate<String, User> kafkaTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public Producer(KafkaTemplate<String, User> kafkaTemplate) {
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
    }

    void sendMessage(User user) {
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(this.TOPIC, user.getName().toString(), user);
        log.info(String.format("Produced user -> %s", user));
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      group-id: group_id
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092



topic:
  name: users
  partitions-num: 1
  replication-factor: 1
```

Comment: do you need http there?

Answer (score 3):

Add the string mapping as `properties`

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
    # Setup Confluent Settings in respective client
    producer:
      value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka...
    consumer:
      value-deserializer: io.confluent.kafka...
    properties:
      # default url for schema registry is localhost:8081 if it is not supplied
      "[schema.registry.url]": http://localhost:8081
```

Docs - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka.additional-properties

Comment: Apparently they changed the format. It used to be spring.kafka.schema...  Great thing I found your post. Thanks man :)

Comment: Well, then I must have had a wrong configuration in my old setup (totally plausible lol). Still, thank you for sharing the configuration :)

Comment: @ETisREAL Sure, you could have had code with `@Value("spring.kafka.schema...")`, but then that is technically manual config

Comment: yup, that was actually was I was doing